# How to send push notification to logged in users only in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

I'm using a integrating MobilePush in Salesforce MarketingCloud into a react-native app.

And I'm using this library https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk

I tested it with binding the device id running the app via XCode on device and it works. But I need to send the push notification to logged in users by logged in email. How can I do that ? I tried setting logged in email as the contact key via `MCReactModule.setContactKey(email);` but in the salesforce marketingcloud mobile push. under the contacts I don't see the email.

How can I get this fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try retriving contactkey by email from SFMC first and then perform the send using actual contactkey

Comment: You meant get the contact key first from email through the API and set it and then try to send the email to that particular contact ?